# How do I convert this SQL into LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

How Do I convert this sql query:

```sql
select * from Trades where tradestatus = 1 and tradetype = 1 and maturitydate < GETDATE() and referenceId not in (select referenceid from Trades where tradetype = 2)
```

to LINQ.

I got stuck at this point:

```
_unitOfWork.TreasuryBillsRepository.Find(t => t.TradeStatus == 1 && t.MaturityDate < DateTime.Now && t.ReferenceId != )
```

Comment: So, post your repository interface and UOW also. Without that I can not understand how you made your life more difficult.

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must write like this:

```
 _unitOfWork.TreasuryBillsRepository.Find(t => t.TradeStatus == 1 && t.MaturityDate < DateTime.Now && _unitOfWork.ReferenceRepository.Where(r=>r.tradetype = 2).Select(r=>r.ReferenceId ).Contains(t.ReferenceId) == false )
```

Comment: `&& !...` is shorter than `== false`

Comment: Yes, of course, I just wanted focus on 'false' :)

Comment: Thank you Mohammad